# How do i change the character encoding of this file with iconv or recode?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iconv

I have a text file that is ISO-8859-1 encoded. I need it utf-8 encoded.
Firefox displays the quote and single quote characters correctly but gedit doesn't:
Firefox:
For The Home Depot?
“Absolutely,” he said at the time. 
Home Depot said Nardelli’s decision

gedit:
For The Home Depot? 
ÂAbsolutely,Â he said at the time. 
Home Depot said NardelliÂs decision

I tried:

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 Bus16451112.txt > iconv.txt
```

and

```
recode ISO-8859-1..UTF-8 Bus16451112.txt
```

Both didn't work. After the conversion firefox displays the characters wrong too regardless if i choose utf-8 ( Absolutely, he said at the time. ) or ISO-8859-1 ( Â“Absolutely,Â” he said at the time. ) in the view menu.

What do i have to do to get this file converted to UTF-8 so it gets displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text file is most certainly not encoded in ISO-8859-1 since that character set does not contain the typographical quote characters. The encoding is probably [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which replaces some control characters of ISO-8859-1 with other more useful characters. You should be able to convert it with iconv like this:

```
iconv -f Windows-1252 -t UTF-8 q8402932.txt > iconv.txt
```